# Javascript onclick function doesnt execute (error log - not defined)

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I can't get this for the life of me...

I've tried to make a mobile friendly nav that gets hidden if the screen res is less than 600px and a button appears that toggles the menu opacity.

https://jsfiddle.net/ef3mezk5/

Here is the fiddle... I have defined the function at the onclick as simply as possible -

```
<div class="menu-icon-black" id="menu-icon" onclick="menudrop()">
```

i am using a separate file that holds the JS engine code here is the portion that is responsible for the menu drop

```
  function menudrop() {
    document.getElementById("menu-icon").classList.toggle("change");

    document.getElementById("navlist").classList.toggle("show");
  }
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: menudrop is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):169)

And i can see its clearly defined... what is going on here?
Can someone please look into this and tell me whats wrong?

Comment: The jsfiddle site is wrapping your code inside another function that's set up as the "load" event handler. You can configure it to do otherwise, but that's the default.

Comment: If you click on options in fiddle, and choose load type "No wrap - in <head>", it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have chosen improper `load type` at jsfiddle. Instead of `load type - on load` use `no wrap - in body`.

Credits to @Pointy.

[image]

```js
  function menudrop() {
    document.getElementById("menu-icon").classList.toggle("change");

    document.getElementById("navlist").classList.toggle("show");
  }
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navlist {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    right: 15%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .navlist li {
    border: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    float: none;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

.navlist {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.navlist li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

.navlist a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s;
  /* vendorless fallback */
  -o-transition: color 0.3s;
  /* opera */
  -ms-transition: color 0.3s;
  /* IE 10 */
  -moz-transition: color 0.3s;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s;
  /*safari and chrome */
  position: relative;
}

.navlist a:hover {
  color: #00bff3;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-icon-black {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon-bar1,
.menu-icon-bar2,
.menu-icon-bar3 {
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Rotate first bar */

.change .menu-icon-bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 7px);
}


/* Fade out the second bar */

.change .menu-icon-bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* Rotate last bar */

.change .menu-icon-bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navlist" id="navlist">
  <li><a href="">Начало</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Планограма</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Запитване</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Реклама при нас</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="menu-icon-black" id="menu-icon" onclick="menudrop()">
  <div class="menu-icon-bar1"></div>
  <div class="menu-icon-bar2"></div>
  <div class="menu-icon-bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not an error; by default jsfiddle wraps all the JavaScript code in a "load" handler, so all the symbols defined are local to that function.

Comment: it doesnt run on my website :D the site isnt live its on my local machine but the code is the same.... i cant figure out whats going on

Comment: Where are you including your js?

Comment: Again, by default jsfiddle wraps **all** the code in the JavaScript pane inside a function. That function is set up as a "load" event handler. Because all the code is wrapped in a function, none of the symbols declared are global. When you use "onclick" etc to set up handlers, the functions referenced must be global. So it's not a bug; it's intended behavior on the part of jsfiddle. That behavior can be changed via the options menu in the JavaScript panel.

Comment: Fine by me. Also see Armin's comment on the question.

Comment: hell what do I know about life.. well it works on jsfiddle now but not on my website... guess im gonna start rebuilding from ground 0 than :D thanks for the help tho , its gonna help me diagnose problems easier now