# Javascript onkeyup function - function is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHhQF/15/) where I want to call a function on keyup event, but I get function not defined. What is wrong with this code:
Html:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("fname");
    var para = document.createElement("p");
        var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
        para.appendChild(node);

    if (input.value < 3){
        input.appendChild(para);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function is set to run "onLoad" and not wrapped in head/body, which means that when you have a keyup event, the code you have written is no longer in scope and is undefined

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491561/javascript-onclick-function-doesnt-execute-error-log-not-defined/42491589#42491589

Comment: In other words, `myFunction` must be global for the `onkeyup` to be able to access it.

Comment: isn't it global already, when it is just set as function declaration?